# Angular JS left Panel slider with animation for mobile app (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive, angularjs-animation

Please help me to get left panel slider for mobile app using angular js. i want my mobile app to be light weight.
**Excluding** cases not using any **bootstrap**,**ui** **bootstrap**,**ionic**,**no native** features

Comment: what exactly do you want? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/ maybe this link can help?

Or you can create a template app using `$ionic start myApp sidemenu` in cmd

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments
i have started creating app with angualr js and not used ionic ..and its reached  a lot. please help me tom implement without ionic implementation